# creating a function to return average daily pm2.5 values from data stored in a dictionary with timestamps and pm2.5 values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, timestamp, pickle

Disclaimer I just started learning python, so I have very little clue what I am doing. This is my code so far, my **average day** function is overly complicated and does not work. It should return the average pm2.5 value for each day. The timestamps are difficult to work with since they are in this format: 2022-05-31 23:59:14.683
If anyone has an idea of how to create such a function the help would be much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pickled_filename = '6months2022.pkl'
sensor_codes = [
    'A1WP33WP',
    'AP4LRGQY',
    'AJJT4NLG',
    'A4189DSH',
    'AJ10LCSL',
    'AXP8VML2',
    'A6WQ2THX',
    'AH1XJYKX',
    'AD1WC8XL',
    'APT4GRPP'
]

def create_sensor_dataframes(pickled_filename):
    # Load pickled data into a list of dictionaries
    with open(pickled_filename, 'rb') as pickled_file:
        raw_data = pickle.load(pickled_file)

    # Create a dictionary to store DataFrames for each sensor
    sensor_dataframes = {}

    for sensor in sensor_codes:
        # Check if data is available for the current sensor
        if sensor in raw_data:
            data = raw_data[sensor]

            # Create a DataFrame for the current sensor
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
            df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.get('time'), format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

            df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

            # Store the DataFrame in the dictionary with the sensor code as the key
            sensor_dataframes[sensor] = df

    return sensor_dataframes

def average_day_clarity_dt(sensor_dataframes):
    final_datapoints_pm25 = {}

    for sensor, df in sensor_dataframes.items():
        claritydf = pd.DataFrame(df)
        length = len(claritydf)
        curindex = 0
        daily_avg_data = []

        while curindex < length:
            # Use .get() to safely access 'time'
            time_value = claritydf.iloc[curindex].get('time') #doesnt work returns none
        

            if time_value is not None:
                start_day = time_value.normalize()
                end_day = start_day + pd.Timedelta(days=1) - pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
                clip = claritydf.loc[(claritydf['time'] >= start_day) & (claritydf['time'] <= end_day)]
                avgPM2_5 = clip['pm2.5'].mean()

                daily_avg_data.append(avgPM2_5)

                curindex += len(clip)
            else:
                # Handle the case where 'time' is None
                curindex += 1

        final_datapoints_pm25[sensor] = daily_avg_data

    return final_datapoints_pm25
```

My create sensor dataframes function works correctly, however, I keep running into issues with the timestamps. I have tried converting the timestamps to julian time but was unable to get that to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.